# Negative Sampling in JAX

Tags: python, jax

I'm implementing a negative sampling algorithm in JAX. The idea is to sample negatives from a range excluding from this range a number of non-acceptable outputs. My current solution is close to the following:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax
max_range = 5
n_samples = 2
true_cases = jnp.array(
    [
        [1,2],
        [1,4],
        [0,5]
    ]
)
# i combine the true cases in a dictionary of the following form:
non_acceptable_as_negatives = {
    0: jnp.array([5]),
    1: jnp.array([2,4]),
    2: jnp.array([]),
    3: jnp.array([]),
    4: jnp.array([]),
    5: jnp.array([])
}
negatives = []
key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)
for i in true_cases[:,0]:
    key,use_key  = jax.random.split(key,2)
    p = jnp.ones((max_range+1,))
    p = p.at[non_acceptable_as_negatives[int(i)]].set(0)
    p = p / p.sum()
    negatives.append(
        jax.random.choice(use_key,
            jnp.arange(max_range+1),
            (1, n_samples),
            replace=False,
            p=p,
            )
    )
```

However this seems

- rather complicated and
- is not very performant as the true cases in the original contain ~200_000 entries and max range is ~ 50_000.

How can I improve this solution? And is there a more JAX way to store arrays of varying size which I currently store in the non_acceptable_as_negatives dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll generally achieve better performance in JAX (as in NumPy) if you can avoid loops and use vectorized operations instead. If I'm understanding your function correctly, I think the following does roughly the same thing, but using `vmap`.

Since JAX does not support dictionary lookups based on traced values, I replaced your dict with a padded array

```py
import jax.numpy as jnp
import jax
max_range = 5
n_samples = 2
fill_value = max_range + 1

true_cases = jnp.array([
  [1,2],
  [1,4],
  [0,5]
])

non_acceptable_as_negatives = jnp.array([
    [5, fill_value],
    [2, 4],
])

@jax.vmap
def func(key, true_case):
  p = jnp.ones(max_range + 1)
  idx = true_cases[0]
  replace = non_acceptable_as_negatives.at[idx].get(fill_value=fill_value)
  p = p.at[replace].set(0, mode='drop')
  return jax.random.choice(key, max_range + 1, (n_samples,), replace=False, p=p)


key = jax.random.PRNGKey(42)
keys = jax.random.split(key, len(true_cases))
result = func(keys, true_cases)
print(result)
```

```
[[3 1]
 [5 1]
 [1 5]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Jax array are immutable. It means that you can't edit it without copying the entire array. Here the main problem is that you create the vector `p` two times at each iteration. I advice you to compute the probabilities only once via numpy:

```py
import numpy as np

non_acceptable_as_negatives = {
    0: np.array([5]),
    1: np.array([2,4]),
    2: np.array([]),
    3: np.array([]),
    4: np.array([]),
    5: np.array([])
}

probas = np.ones((max_range+1, max_range+1))
for k, idx in non_acceptable_as_negatives.items():
    for i in idx:
        probas[k, i] = 0
probas = probas / probas.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)
probas = jnp.array(probas)
```

Then, to further speed-up the algorithm, you can compile the `choice` function. You can try:

```py
from functools import partial

@partial(jax.jit, static_argnums=1)
def sample(key, max_range, probas):
    key, use_key  = jax.random.split(key, 2)
    return jax.random.choice(use_key,
            jnp.arange(max_range+1),
            (1, n_samples),
            replace=False,
            p=probas[i],
            ), key
```

And finally:

```
for i in true_cases[:,0]:
    neg, key = aux(key, max_range, probas)
    negatives.append(neg)
```